# Remove above line if matched keyword is found

Tags: awk, sed, grep, gawk

I have a data something like this:

```
Amit:   
  Mem  30  40 50  
Sumit:  
  Mem  50 70 80   
Tarun:  
Nishant:  
  Mem  90 20 45
```

As in "Tarun:",Mem is not present need to remove it.

final output should be

```
Amit:   
  Mem  30  40 50   
Sumit:   
  Mem  50 70 80   
Nishant:   
  Mem  90 20 45
```

Please help me to get this resolve. I have tried but not able to get the required output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed '$!N;/\n  Mem/p;D' file
Amit:
  Mem  30  40 50
Sumit:
  Mem  50 70 80
Nishant:
  Mem  90 20 45
```

- `$!N`: For every line that is not the last line, append the next line to the buffer with a delimiting newline in-between.
- `/\n  Mem/p`: If the buffer now contains a newline character immediately followed by the string   `Mem` (two spaces and `Mem`), then print the buffer. You may also use `[[:blank:]]*` in place of the two spaces to allow for any amount of spaces or tabs at the start of the `Mem` lines.
- `D`: Delete the data in the buffer up to and including the first newline character, and start the next cycle.

Comment: Excellent !!!! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will be generic code  Only Mem present it will print previous line

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/Mem/{for(x=NR-1;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' file
```

output

```
Amit:   
  Mem  30  40 50  
Sumit:  
  Mem  50 70 80   
Nishant:  
  Mem  90 20 45
```